# How to count how often a specific value appears in a column of a data.frame in R

Tags: r

I´ve downloaded a dataset from OpenML https://www.openml.org/search?type=data
Intentionally I picked a dataset with many features and "0 missing values". Now I found that some features have the value '?'. Therefore I would like to count for every feature how often the value '?' appears (in that column of my data.frame).

My question seems so easy but I´m sorry, I did not find an answer so far. Everything I tried so far seems to be a bit "overkill" and is not working:

**frequency**
I tried out frequency. I think somewhere I picked up that it´s supposed to give me a list of what values occur and how often. But trying it out I found that "frequency returns the number of samples per unit time and deltat the time interval between observations (see ts)."

```
[1] 1
> frequency(phpvqZpLa[,2])
[1] 1
> frequency(phpvqZpLa)
[1] 1
> ?frequency
```

**table**
I thought about using table. But that´s not really what I want. I´m looking for something so much simpler :D

I am quite new to R and this is my second question in this forum. Therefore I am very happy about helpful answers for my question but also about comments on how I could/ should improove my question or a link to a very similar question (which I did not find before)

**edit**
after I tried out the suggestion of Shibaprasadb (which seemed to answer my problem) the questionmarks were not counted correctly:

```
> colSums(phpvqZpLa[,6]=='?')
weight 
     0 

> phpvqZpLa[1,6]
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  weight
  <chr> 
1 '?'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always try to provide a dummy data frame. That makes the job quite easier.

You can do this:

```
#Creating a dummy data frame

a <- c(1, 2, 4,'?', 58, 90, '?')
b <- c('?', 89, 90, 100, '?', 67, 900)
c <- c(57, 71, '?', '?', '?',76, 90)

df <- data.frame(a,b,c)

colSums(df=='?')
```

Output:

```
a b c 
2 2 3
```

Comment: That looks great, it´s so short and easy, thanks a lot! It defenitely answered my question. 
But it also raised a new question for me: with the data from OpenML it does not work for some reason. Does it still belong here or shall I create a new question? 
So I tried it out and it said there is 0 questionmarks but the whole column is full of questionmarks. Is there maybe a problem because the ? is a character and not a number? It feels like I need to say ...==' '?' ' (because I might be looking for '?' and not just for ? but when I try it out that does not work)

Comment: code in here does not look nice - i will edit the original question

Comment: @oaktree from the link you shared, which data set you're working with? And yes, from the next time use ```dput(head(df, n))``` where n is the number of rows and share the sample data frame. It will make things easier for everyone.

Comment: I tried to do dput(head(df,n)) but my dataset is too large for that. it has 50 features and 101.766 entries. Therefore I only used head() and added a link to find the dataset. I made a new question for that because I will delete this one soon (because a similar question has been found). Maybe you could have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69177344/how-to-count-in-r-in-a-dataset-from-openml and let me know if this question is better or how I could improove it?

Answer (score 2):

the tidyverse, specially dplyr, are excellent for these operations.
Using the example data by *@danloo* . We can first replace all `?` values with NA. There is a function designed specifically for that, `na_if`. After that we use normal dplyr synthax to `summarise` with a list of functions, which are `sum(is.na(.x)`, which sums the NA elements, and mean(is.na(.x)), wich gets us the rate of NAs, for every (`everything()`) column.
:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% na_if("?") %>%
        summarise(across(everything(), list(sum=~sum(is.na(.x)), mean=~mean(is.na(.x)))))

# A tibble: 1 x 4
  col_a_sum col_a_mean col_b_sum col_b_mean
      <int>      <dbl>     <int>      <dbl>
1         1       0.25         2        0.5
```

With the data from *@Shibaprasadb*

```
  a_sum    a_mean b_sum    b_mean c_sum    c_mean
1     2 0.2857143     2 0.2857143     3 0.4285714
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(
  col_a = c("?", "a", "b", "c"),
  col_b = c("f", "?", "?", "g")
)
data
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   col_a col_b
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 ?     f    
#> 2 a     ?    
#> 3 b     ?    
#> 4 c     g

data %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  mutate(is_na = value == "?") %>%
  count(name, is_na) %>%
  filter(is_na) %>%
  select(name, n)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   name      n
#>   <chr> <int>
#> 1 col_a     1
#> 2 col_b     2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>