# how to count '?' in R in a dataset from openML

Tags: r

This is a follow-up to my question [How to count how often a specific value appears in a column of a data.frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69175538/how-to-count-how-often-a-specific-value-appears-in-a-column-of-a-data-frame-in-r/69175788?noredirect=1#comment122265231_69175788) (I will delete that one soon because a similar question has been found)

I am working on the dataset Diabetes130US from OpenML: https://www.openml.org/d/4541
It has 50 features and "0 missing values". But some values are only '?'
Therefore now I want to count for each feature how many values are missing and then reduce the dataset by features that have too many missing values.

```
> (head(phpvqZpLa))
# A tibble: 6 x 50
  encounter_id patient_nbr race  gender age   weight admission_type_~ discharge_dispo~
         <dbl>       <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>             <dbl>            <dbl>
1      2278392     8222157 'Cau~ 'Fema~ '[0-~ '?'                   6               25
2       149190    55629189 'Cau~ 'Fema~ '[10~ '?'                   1                1
3        64410    86047875 'Afr~ 'Fema~ '[20~ '?'                   1                1
4       500364    82442376 'Cau~ 'Male' '[30~ '?'                   1                1
5        16680    42519267 'Cau~ 'Male' '[40~ '?'                   1                1
6        35754    82637451 'Cau~ 'Male' '[50~ '?'                   2                1
# ... with 42 more variables: admission_source_id <dbl>, time_in_hospital <dbl>,
#   payer_code <chr>, medical_specialty <chr>, num_lab_procedures <dbl>,
#   num_procedures <dbl>, num_medications <dbl>, number_outpatient <dbl>,
#   number_emergency <dbl>, number_inpatient <dbl>, diag_1 <chr>, diag_2 <chr>,
#   diag_3 <chr>, number_diagnoses <dbl>, max_glu_serum <chr>, A1Cresult <chr>,
#   metformin <chr>, repaglinide <chr>, nateglinide <chr>, chlorpropamide <chr>,
#   glimepiride <chr>, acetohexamide <chr>, glipizide <chr>, glyburide <chr>,
#   tolbutamide <chr>, pioglitazone <chr>, rosiglitazone <chr>, acarbose <chr>,
#   miglitol <chr>, troglitazone <chr>, tolazamide <chr>, examide <chr>, citoglipton <chr>,
#   insulin <chr>, glyburide.metformin <chr>, glipizide.metformin <chr>,
#   glimepiride.pioglitazone <chr>, metformin.rosiglitazone <chr>,
#   metformin.pioglitazone <chr>, change <chr>, diabetesMed <chr>, readmitted <chr>
```

From the previous question I know how I could count questionmarks in theory:

```
#Creating a dummy data frame

a <- c(1, 2, 4,'?', 58, 90, '?')
b <- c('?', 89, 90, 100, '?', 67, 900)
c <- c(57, 71, '?', '?', '?',76, 90)

df <- data.frame(a,b,c)

colSums(df=='?')
```

Output:

```
a b c 
2 2 3
```

But for some reason this does not work for my dataset from OpenML:

```
> colSums(phpvqZpLa[,6]=='?')
weight 
     0
```

Let´s see if there should be a questionmark in column 6 of this dataset:

```
> phpvqZpLa[1,6]
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  weight
  <chr> 
1 '?'
```

Comment: Why not replacing all `?` in your data with NA followed by "R's standard procedure of (simple) data analysis"?

Comment: Already answered! See @GuedesBF detailed answer in the previous question. Modify if needed, `"'?'" ` <-> `"?"`.

Comment: @Pax thanks! I just did not see how to do this modification, but now it´s solved! 
I am quite new to this community. is this question so simple/ specific that I should delete it again so that there are not too many "dumb questions" ins this forum? Or is it normal to just leave it here in case someone else has a similar problem AND comes across this question?

Comment: I think you should be able to modify @GuedesBF answer! Also, I recommend to tackle issues by reading and trying! Between your answers are only minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataset has quotes around character values, so use -

```
colSums(phpvqZpLa == "'?'")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
phpvqZpLa %>%
   summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(. == "'?'", na.rm = TRUE)))
```